# ZF3 session timeout issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have been facing issue related to Session timeout using Zend Framework 3. Session expired within 5-10 min. I had used the default code for the session, which Zf3 skeleton provides in **global.php** as below.

```
// Session configuration.
'session_config' => [   
  'cookie_lifetime' => 60*60*1, // Session cookie will expire in 1 hour.
  'gc_maxlifetime' => 60*60*1,  // Store session data on server maximum for 1 hour. 
],

// Session manager configuration. 
'session_manager' => 
[
   'validators' => [
      RemoteAddr::class,
      HttpUserAgent::class,
    ]
],

// Session storage configuration.
'session_storage' => [
   'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class 
],
```

After using above code still session expired within 5-10 minutes.I want session expired time more than 30 minutes.How to configure it in Zf3.

Please provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct settings for the session manager, but this is not enough for these session settings to be used as the default one.

My assumption is that you do not make this session manager your default one. In order to make it, you need to instantiate it as early as possible.
One solution would be to do this is in module **Module.php**

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

class Module
{
    //...

    /**
     * This method is called once the MVC bootstrapping is complete. 
     */
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();

        // The following line instantiates the SessionManager and automatically
        // makes the SessionManager the 'default' one.
        $sessionManager = $serviceManager->get(SessionManager::class);
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Working_with_Sessions/Session_Manager.html)

EDIT: My 2nd assumption is that you use the global path for your sessions(eg /var/lib/php/sessions).

In Debian, there is a cron that may clear sessions according to your php.ini session settings(/etc/cron.d/php).

This cron uses your php.ini "gc_maxlifetime" and probably clears your sessions.

To find out where your sessions are saved, use ***session_save_path()***. Check that directory for your sessions.

To overcome this, you should set **"save_path"** and this path should not be shared with others applications or scripts on your server(you do not want another script using the global gc settings or its own, deleting your sessions).

Add

```
'save_path'           =>   '/path/to/app/data/sessions'
```

in your 'session_config' array.

Comment: after using above code Still session is expired within 5-10 minutes.Please provide solution for this.                                                                             
Any other configuration for session which i had missed?

Comment: Can you add the code where you are using the session and how you see it expires?

Comment: Using my above code in global.php session expire within 10 minutes.After adding your code in module file still session expire within 10 minutes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is it a user login that expires? If so, can you add the code where you log in the user?

Comment: I want login session atleast 30 minutes.
I used code from https://github.com/olegkrivtsov/using-zf3-book-samples/blob/master/userdemo/module/User/src/Controller/AuthController.php

Comment: still my login session expired with 15 minutes if in ideal

Comment: Can you try to set the save_path also in your settings and test if it works now: 'session_config' => [   
  'cookie_lifetime' => 60*60*1,
  'gc_maxlifetime' => 60*60*1, 'save_path' => '/path/to/session'
]   Change /path/to/session to a local path eg userdemo/data/session which is writable by the apache user in your system?