# ZF3 logout after some inactive session

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, zend-session

How to auto logout session after some inactive? I want this functionality in zend framework 3.If anyone have idea then let me inform please.Currently my application logout within 5 minutes with the used of zend skeleton.But I want session expiration time atleast 30 minutes.

Please provide solution for above.

Comment: which server OS do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04,LAMP

Answer (score 0):

Just add this session configuration in your `module.config.php`, and make sure `Zend\Session` has been added in `config/modules.config.php`

```
use Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage;

return [
    // your existing config 

    'session_config' => [
        'cookie_lifetime' => 60 * 30
    ],
    'session_storage' => [
        'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks Dolly Aswin.

But using above solutions,I had already try.Please refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801013/zf3-session-timeout-issue